# Take Screenshot on Windows and save it?

Tags: python, save, screenshot

i want to take a screenshot , using python , (Windows Only) and SAVE IT !
i am using pyscreenshot library and PIL

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

img = ImageGrab.grab()


plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')
plt.save('img.png')
```

Comment: What is the program? What are the results of your code?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

# fullscreen
im=ImageGrab.grab()
im.show()

# part of the screen
im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))
im.show()

# to file
ImageGrab.grab_to_file('im.png')
```

Comment: i cant post the whole error , but it's something like :- An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: Borrowed from http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=2681009&postcount=5